# Unable to apply ReplaceToken in gradle kotlin dsl

Tags: kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

Am trying to migrate gradle groovy to kotlin dsl. But am not able to find a replacement for `

> filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: ["version" to project.version])

`. I want to replace token for all the tasks not just one. i tried expand, but its not working when trying to apply for all the tasks.

```
configure(allTasks) { //alltask is a list of tasks
        expand("version" to project.version)
    }
```

fails, asks to import expand.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We resolved the issue using the below code

```
tasks.withType<ProcessResources> {
    filter<ReplaceTokens>(
        "tokens" to mapOf(
            "version" to project.version,
        ),
    )
}
```

All our tasks were of type pricessResource so this solved my issue.